# Unhandled exception at 0x00428252 in assignment_3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004

Tags: visual-studio-2010, access-violation, unhandled-exception

I'm using VS2010 and I am getting the error in the title from the line "mov dword ptr [edx], eax". It's a simple program that uses recursion to find factorials and calls a separate function factorial to get the factorial of an input. I'm testing it with the input 5 and "call factorial" is returning 120 (as it should) but when I try to store it back into the output I am getting the error and I'm not sure why.

```
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edx

    mov ebx, dword ptr[16 + esp] // input
    mov edx, dword ptr[20 + esp] // &output
    mov eax, ebx // copy ecx

    call factorial

    mov dword ptr [edx], eax
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx

    ret
```

Factorial :

```
    sub ebx, 1 // eax - 1
    cmp ebx, 1 // if eax equals 1 then end of recursion
    je skip
    push ebx

    call factorial
    pop ebx
    skip:
    mul ebx // multiply ebx * eax
    ret
```

Comment: Could you provide the source code, not the disassembly?